# 非パッチ適用状態にあるNetworkManagerをLinuxディストリビューションで直接利用できないのは何故か？

Tags: linux, unix

### 概要

以前メイン機のNetworkMangerが壊れてしまったので、[CDにクローンしておいた](https://github.com/freedesktop/NetworkManager)NetworkMangerのビルドを試み、成功はしたものの、動きませんでした。また調べてみた所Redditのスレットがヒットし、回答者は、

> NetworkManagerのような古典的なプログラムは、パッチを当てる事によりそれぞれのディストリビューションに最適化されます。あなたがDebianユーザで在るなら、専用のパッケージからロードして下さい（原文ママ）

と書かれておりこちらもリポジトリから落とした`pkg.tar.xz`パッケージをダウンロードしたという経緯があります。

この点を踏まえて先生方にお伺いしたことがあります。

- 何故古典的なパッケージはパッチがないと動かないのか？
- またこのような古典的なパッケージが生で動くOSはどのようなOSなのか？
- そもそもこのようなパッケージは最適化され運用される事を前提としているのか？

少し雑な質問になってしまいましたが以上が伺いたい事の全てです。

Comment: 少なくとも、何のディストリビューションを使っているのかと、引用元のURLを含めるべきかと思います。

Comment: 詳しい回答は出来ませんが、例えば Debian であれば Network Manager に対する [パッチが公開されている](https://sources.debian.org/patches/network-manager/) ので、中身を確認すれば何をしているのかがある程度分かるんじゃないかと思います。

Comment: 先に返信がかなり遅くなってしまった事、そしてソースが不透明であった事をお詫びします。パッチが公開されていたことに関しては盲点でした。早速調べさせていただきました。回答していただきありがとうございました。